# Collecting music artists by scraping websites using BeautifulSoup recursively

Tags: python, recursion, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i'm working on a project to collect names of musicians / groups / artists, and i started working on this website: https://www.canzoni.it/artisti/lettera/a (that has a simple html structure). my goal is to collect all the names that are in this section, from A to Z. I thought to create a function and to work recoursively. here's the code:

```
def crawl_canzoni_it(url, base = 'https://www.canzoni.it'):
    links=[]
    artists=[]
    r = requests.get(base+url).text
    obj = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
    for i in obj.select('.ul_freccia li'):
        for link in i.findAll('a'):
            links.append(link['href'])
    for i in obj.select('.ul_freccia li'):
        for link in i.findAll('a'):
            artists.append(link.text)
    for i in obj.findAll('a'):
        if i.has_attr('title'):
            if i['title'] == 'Vai alla pagina Successiva':
                print(base+i['href'])
                crawl_canzoni_it(i['href'])
            else:
                pass
        else: pass
    return artists, links
```

one of the problems is that the two lists returned contains the **first** page of names (that is https://www.canzoni.it/artisti/lettera/a/1 and not the last one (https://www.canzoni.it/artisti/lettera/a/8) and I don't understand why.

for the second problem i know that doing like this, my program don't store all that i need in the lists "links" and "artists" because at every loop, they are reinitialized, but i don't know how to do to obtain at the end, the full lists.

Comment: _for the second problem i know that doing like this, my program don't store all that i need in the lists "links" and "artists" because at every loop, they are reinitialized, but i don't know how to do to obtain at the end, the full lists._ Pass the lists around as parameters? Although I don't think using recursion is a good idea.

Comment: This doesn't look like a good excuse to use recursion. And obviously, since you are using recursion, the lists you return are only from the first request, all the work done by the other calls is being discarded. You don't even look at what the recursive call to `crawl_canzoni_it()` is returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding second problem .In each recursion call your links and artists is re initialised.So outside function you can create other list and at end of function you can append that link to it.